# pandas dataframe - drop remaining rows based on specific column value

Tags: pandas

I wanted to drop remaining rows on pandas dataframe when the specific column value has that value.

For example, if the col1 has value as "FEB", drop remaining all rows including that row.

**Code:**

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, usecols=range(32, 89), skiprows=9).dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: Add a small example dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case using `argmax`

```
yourdf=df.iloc[:df.col1.eq('FEB').values.argmax(),:].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `cumsum`:

```
df = df[df['col1'].eq('FEB').cumsum().eq(0)]
```

Test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['JAN', 'MAY', 'FEB', 'JAN', 'FEB'],
                   'col2': [1,2,3,4,5]}) 

  col1  col2
0  JAN     1
1  MAY     2
2  FEB     3
3  JAN     4
4  FEB     5
```

output:

```
    col1    col2
0   JAN     1
1   MAY     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invert (~) operator:

```
df=df[~df['col1'].str.match('FEB')]
```

to select number, you can directly use:

```
new_dataframe=df[df.col1 != #put number here]
```